# How to resolve differences between the php.ini and in the php -i output?

Tags: php, configuration, php-7, php-7.2, memory-limit

I have PHP 7.2 runing on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 12.

Now I wanted to see, what the current `memory_limit` is. I did it three ways and got different results:

**`php -i`**

```
$ php -i | grep "memory_limit"
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
```

**`ini_get(...)`**

```
$ php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit') . PHP_EOL;"
256M
```

**`php.ini`**

```
$  php -i | grep "php.ini"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php7/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php7/cli/php.ini
$ nano /etc/php7/cli/php.ini
...
memory_limit = 128M
```

As can easily be seen, the checks' results of `php -i` and `ini_get(...)` differs from that of the `php.ini`'.

**What might it be caused by? What value is the correct one? How to make and keep the configurations consistent (if they are currently not).**

Comment: If you run `php --ini`, are there any additional files listed that could be overriding it?

Comment: @iainn Thank you very much for this comment! Sure, there are some included `.ini` files. But usually those files only contain the extension specific configs and don't affect the basic settings. So I didn't get the idea to take a look at them. Now I checked them and voilà, there is actually one `.ini` (the `i-doit.ini`) that sets the `memory_limit` to `256M`. Thank you again! Feel free to make an answer from your comment.